# Getting error while filtering record based on time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql-aggregation

I have few record for a user in my collection. For that record insertion time is in `toISOString` format. I am trying to ignore the record which is more than 3 days old using find query but getting some error.

error: error in query: fail to parse content of query: invalid character '.' after array element

myRecord:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "user1",
    "data":"some data",
    "insertionTime": "2020-11-10T10:18:27.158Z",
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
     "name": "user1",
    "data":"some data"
    "insertionTime": "2020-11-10T14:18:27.158Z",
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
     "name": "user1",
    "data":"some data",
    "insertionTime": "2020-11-06T14:18:27.158Z",
  }
]
```

expected output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2",
     "name": "user1",
    "data":"some data",
    "insertionTime": "2020-11-10T14:18:27.158Z",
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
     "name": "user1",
    "data":"some data",
    "insertionTime": "2020-11-10T14:18:27.158Z",
  }
]
```

Query i tried:

```
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $and: [ { $eq: ['$name', 'user1'] }, { $gte: [ { $dateFromString: { dateString: '$insertionTime' } }, new Date(Date.now() - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), ], }, ], }, });
```

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: query:

db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      { $eq: ['$name', 'user1'] },
      {
        $gte: [
          { $dateFromString: { dateString: '$insertionTime' } },
          new Date(Date.now() - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is in this line `new Date(Date.now() - 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

You have to use [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) to perform subtraction.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $eq: [
          "$name",
          "user1"
        ]
      },
      {
        $gte: [
          {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: "$insertionTime"
            }
          },
          {
            "$subtract": [
              new Date(Date.now()),
              259200000
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BayJAPfylJo)